# Different horizontal spacing depending on orientaton iOs 8

Tags: ios8, size-classes

I have 3 UIViews in a iOs application. I need them to be 20 point apart if the iPhone is in portrait orientation and 40 point apart if it's in a landscape orientation. I am using size classes. Which size classes I should use to be able to target the horizontal space constraint in this two situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html):

- iPhone portrait: regular Height, compact width
- iPhone landscape: compact Height, compact Width
- iPhone 6+ landscape: compactHeight, regular Width